# BOOTSTRAP RADIO BUTTON with css skin in 2 different panels doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/8p984uc0/

Its 2 different bootstrap panels. (I had 30 panels in the final page) - just to simplify..

I made an stylish RADIO BUTTON using:

```
<label class="btn btn-success-on btn-success-inv bk-fg-white btn-sm bk-rd-off bk-bd-success" style="width: 90px; max-width: 90px;">
<input type="radio" name="CHOICE2" id="CHOICE2" value="1" /><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> CHOICE 01!</label>
```

My problem:

- With this style in radio if I put in different panels - the radio buttons doesnt work. (I check radio 1 - and check radio 2 - and radio 1 continues checked)
- If I put booth in the same panel, no problem.
  (if I check radio 1, and then check radio 2 - radio 1 was unchecked).

Whats is wrong?

tks!!

1- https://jsfiddle.net/8p984uc0/2/ with all radios in the same panel, works fine.

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context (not related to your issue)

Comment: @A.Wolff OP id is not unique so maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: The issue is about the active class (bootstrap js behaviour) wich is relative to `form-group`, only one per `form-group`. Here, your are using two `form-group` so previous active class isn't removed

Answer (score 0):

When you put them in the same panel you also put them in the same button group, I think that's the point.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/u45coLdz/) is an example of your first fiddle working, though the stile is broken.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <div class="panel bk-widget bk-bd-off bk-chrome-fix col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel bk-widget bk-bd-off bk-chrome-fix col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        ....
    </div>
<div>
```

As you can see they are in two different panels, but the button-group is the same.

And [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pzyetfhx/) is an example of your second fiddle that dosn't work, I've put the radio buttons in two different button groups.
Also I'm not sure that you need all those col-lg, col-md, col-sm and col-sx, but that's another question.

**EDIT:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m9u2umro/) is a new fiddle, now the buttons have the right style, and it works. I changed the buttons name to CHOICES, which makes more sense, and then updated the CSS adding

```
input[name=CHOICES] {
    display:none
}
```

Comment: Hi @Denis-Bokor, first of all, tks for your time to help! Yes, you are right! the problem is with DATA-TOGGLE="Buttons" - if I remove this - works fine, in any case. But, without this, I lost the "Style" too - radio button now has a "radio button style" and not the "button button" style. There is a way to fix this? tks a lot! Daniel

Comment: @DANIEL look at my new fiddle,should have solved the problem